# Backbone.js - id vs idAttribute vs cid

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, backbone.js, underscore.js

I've been studying Backbone.js for a few weeks, and I feel comfortable using views with models, routers, and collections.

I still have some big gaps:

1. What is the connection between `id`, `cid`, and `idAttribute`? How do they affect each other?
2. When exactly does a new model get its ID? Is the server responsible for assigning it? Do I need to add it to the `defaults` of the model (maybe as a function)? Maybe the `addNewModel` function should do that?

Answer (score 61):

> What is the connection between `id`, `cid`, and `idAttribute`? How do they affect each other?

Both the [cid](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-cid) and [id](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-id) should be unique id's for the model, and can be used to [retrieve](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-getByCid) a model [from](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-get) a collection.

The difference between the two is that the `cid` is assigned by backbone.js client side and is useful if you don't have an actual id, either because the model hasn't been saved yet to the server or perhaps you aren't even saving it to a db (maybe you're using [localStorage](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/backbone-localstorage.html)). The `id` attribute should be the id of the model that comes from your server (that is what the id is in your db). `idAttribute` tells backbone which "field" coming from your server it should use to update the `id` attribute, by default this is set to "id" but as it says in the [documentation](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-idAttribute) if your server uses something else you can set it to that (the example given is setting it to "_id".

> When exactly does a new model get its ID? Is the server responsible for assigning it? Do I need to add it to the `defaults` of the model (maybe as a function)? Maybe the `addNewModel` function should do that?

They should get the new id's when saved to the [server](http://backbonejs.org/#Sync) and you shouldn't need to set it manually (based on the `idattribute`) unless you need more control over the process.

Answer (score 7):

id - id that might be manually set when the model is created, or is populated when model has been saved on the server (see "idAttribute" at the bottom to see the connection). This is the id that is sent to the server when model is loaded or updated from server e.g., for a model Person this call will be made if id is 123, "/person/123"

cid - unique id set my backbone model for internal use

idAttribute - this decides which property will act as the unique id (default is "id") when the model has been saved on the server e.g., a model's unique key on the server might be defined by "personId", so when fetch is called model will map the server response from "personId" to id in the backbone model.

Answer (score 1):

`id` is server model id, `cid` is client id.

- server model: such as Rails Model
- client model: backbone model

Answer (score 0):

The `id` property on a model is automatically assigned based on the `id` set in the model’s attributes hash. Ideally, this is the ID that you receive from the rest API for the resource that you are querying. On the other hand, `cid` is an ID temporarily assigned to each model and is useful until an actual ID is determined for the object. For example, a model pushed to a collection that has not yet been persisted can be addressed using `cid`, until it is saved in the database and an actual ID is generated for it.