# Find model in Backbone.js collection by cid rather than id

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone.js-collections

Can I use Collection.get(id) to find a model within a Backbone.js collection by cid, for a model not yet saved to the server?

From the documentation, it seems like .get should find a model by either its id or cid.   However, `collection.get(cid)` doesn't find the model, whereas this does, `collection.find(function(model) {return model.cid===cid; })`.  Presumably I'm overlooking something basic.

[jsFiddle for example below](http://jsfiddle.net/gradualstudent/ReTQk/4/)

```
var Element = Backbone.Model.extend({});
var Elements = Backbone.Collection.extend({ model:  Element });

var elements = new Elements(), el, cids = [];

for (var i=0; i<4; i++) {
    el = new Element({name: "element"+i})
    elements.add(el);
    cids.push(el.cid);
}

console.log(cids);
el1 = elements.get(cids[0]);     
console.log(el1);  // undefined


el1a = elements.find(function(model) { return model.cid === cids[0]; });
console.log(el1a);  // success
```

[Backbone.js - id vs idAttribute vs cid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12169822/backbone-js-id-vs-idattribute-vs-cid)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In backbone 0.9.9 ([see changelog](http://backbonejs.org/#changelog)), they removed the `.getByCid()` method and folded that functionality directly into `.get()` -- if you're using below 0.9.9, you can use the `.getByCid()` method; I think they've since removed it from the docs to reflect the most current state of the library.

Edit:

See @Ferdinand Prantl's comment below for more detail, but passing the `cid` as the property of an object literal will accomplish what you're looking for here: `.get({ cid: "xxx" })`.  My apologies for any confusion.

Comment: Use `.get({ cid: "..." })`.  The `id` can be passed directly to the `get`, but `cid` has to be passed as an object literal.  Actually, you can pass the `id` in an object literal too and have your code consistent.

Comment: @Ferdinand Prantl, I've edited my answer.  Thanks for clearing this up.