# Backbone.js : Is cid only used for Models

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

In Backbone.js, there is a property I see called "cid"...Is it used only for Model objects (and not view or collection)

Also are "id" and "idAttribute" used by Model objects only? What is the difference?
It would be great if you could explain with a very basic example.

Comment: http://backbonejs.org/#Model-idAttribute

Comment: possible duplicate of [backbone.js - id vs idAttribute vs cid](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12169822/backbone-js-id-vs-idattribute-vs-cid)

Answer (score 7):

`cid` is a property for Backbone Models that serves as the unique identifier for each model until they are assigned a real `id`. After the model `id` or the attribute that matches the `idAttribute` has been assigned, the `cid` is no longer used. For more information see the [backbone.js docs](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-cid). Also View's have `cid`, but that is more for internal bookkeeping and jquery event binding/unbinding.

`id` is also a special property for models, it is meant to hold the backend identifier for the model (most databases create some sort of identifier for each new entry/row). When this identifier is labeled `id` things work out of the box with Backbone.js, but there are some Databases which label their identifiers differently (for example MongoDB with `_id`).

In these cases Backbone doesn't know out-of-the-box to move that property from the attributes to the `id` -property. This is where `idAttribute` comes in handy: You can define it to point to the label of the identifier from the backed (in MongoDB's case `_id`) and then Backbone knows to assign the given `_id` -attribute to the `id` property.

Example:

```
var noIdModel = new Backbone.Model();
noIdModel.id // this will be undefined
noIdModel.cid // this will be something like c1

var idModel = new Backbone.Model({id: 1});
idModel.id // this will be 1
idModel.cid // this will be something like c2

// extend a model to have an idAttribute
var IdAttributeModel = Backbone.Model.extend({idAttribute: "_id"});
// create and instance of that model
// assign a value for an attribute with the same name as idAttribute
var idAttributeModel = new IdAttributeModel({_id: 1});
idAttributeModel.id // this will be 1
idAttributeModel.cid // this will be something like c3
```

To really drive the point home:

Each time when Backbone Model's `set` is called, it checks if the `idAttribute` is present in the attributes to be set and sets that attribute's value to be the new `id`. This can be witnessed from [this line of code in the Backbone.js source:](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-45)

```
if (this.idAttribute in attrs) this.id = attrs[this.idAttribute];
```

As you can see [the default idAttribute is 'id'](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-34). Setting your own `idAttribute` will result in the Model `id` being set accordingly.

Comment: Thx a lot...Could u pls elaborate on var IdAttributeModel = Backbone.Model.extend({idAttribute: "_id"});
var idAttributeModel = new IdAttributeModel({_id: 1});

Comment: Great answer. One addition: a view has a cid as well.

Comment: I added that to the answer and elaborated on the last example, I reall don't know how to elaborate any further.

Answer (score 0):

from the [backbone.js](http://www.backbone.js) :

> A special property of models, the cid or client id is a unique identifier automatically assigned to all models when they're first created. Client ids are handy when the model has not yet been saved to the server, and does not yet have its eventual true id, but already needs to be visible in the UI.

the idAttribute is almost the same but the difference is it contains the id of a model taken from an existing backend.